# What are these 2 knob-like things on this outlet cover for?

Tags: electrical

What are the 2 knob-like things on the bottom of this outlet cover?  What is their function?

[image: An outlet cover with 2 knobs on the bottom]

[image: A closer look at the knobs]

It appears to be something low voltage:
[image: The inside of outlet]

Comment: it almost looks like old TV antenna terminals, but I've never seen one as part of an electrical outlet

Comment: I would use a sharp utility knife to neatly slice the (multiple) layers of paint around the edge of the cover plate, scrape the paint off the screws and remove it to see what's back there. Probably* a good idea to identify the breaker it's on and turn the breaker off first. * "Probably" as in "you really need to do this, I'm just saying it politely".

Comment: With stuff this old, "open it up and have a look" is something you only want to do if you are prepared to deal with "unintended consequences" - disturbing the ancient wiring and crufty old insulation may result in a sudden need to replace a lot of wiring that might well be a good idea to do, but if you're not in the midst of planning for, might also be a large expense you'd prefer not to have thrust upon you unplanned. Start with AFCI/GFCI breakers as a way to make the ancient and inconvenient wiring less hazardous, if making changes. Might be "when you are replacing the fusebox."

Comment: Did not know polarized outlets were that old(~1900), thought they were younger than I.

Comment: Those could be rubber covers over coax connectors.

Comment: The newly added picture lends credence to the antenna connector theory. We've used coax for antenna feeds for the last 20-30 years, but before that, it was two separate wires.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, but one knob could be a binding post connecting to a longwire antenna in the attic, and the other one could connect to a grounding rod. Early AM radios needed external antennas and had binding posts on the back to connect an antenna wire and a ground wire.

Comment: Or two connectors for a dipole antenna?

Comment: @DaveM All the classic AM radios I've seen that had binding posts for an external antenna had one post labeled ANT or AERIAL and the other GND or the like. The wavelength of the U.S. AM band runs from about 180 to 550 meters, so a legit dipole antenna for AM would be a ponderous affair, eh? Before ferrite rod antennas, it was commonplace to just string a long wire somewhere in the house as an antenna and connect the ground terminal to a steam pipe or radiator. The pictured outlet may have offered a more elegant solution.

Comment: That time is a smidgen before mine.  Though I have constructed my own ham antennas on my childhood home.  This looks like something that could be in an apartment building where some sort of wiring was built in.  It's so covered in old paint it's hard to tell what kind of terminals they are.

Comment: The recently added picture lends some credence to this theory.

Comment: The third photo strongly suggests that the insulated left binding post (left when facing the outlet) is indeed for a radio antenna and the right one is for a radio ground. Suggest that the OP not use this ground for any electric wiring purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't exactly match examples I'm sure of.

Probably an old two-button switch. Push one for on and the other for off, of whatever it controls, if still hooked up. Given the amount of paint slopped over everything, replacement might be wise.

Alternate possibility would be twist to switch, or perhaps even twist to dim. In which case it would be two switches, most likely, or one switch and a related dimmer.

Comment: With the way the paint is, was thinking of attachment posts to hold something on(clock?)

Comment: Clock outlets are normally recessed with a hook. The paint I'm just thinking years (decades, perhaps even a century) of careless painting (once the first person paints over them, everyone else feels they need to as well, and there are quite a few layers embedding this poor fixture.

Comment: If the outlet is high up on the wall (which the second picture can be interpreted that way), it could well be a clock outlet.

Comment: The outlet is actually about 1 foot off the ground.